# How to set special price as final price in magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, special-price

I would like to setup the special price as a final price. In the current scenario, what happens, if the `price` columns is lesser than the `special price`, the price is taken as selling price.

**WHY**

There are instances, product price is revised on demand. In such cases, I would like to setup the `special price` slightly higher than the `actual price`.

I have been looking for a setting but, I dont find any. Is there a work around?

Comment: Magento always set lowest price as a final price among all the prices like catalog rule price special price etc.. So if you want you can set Custom Price when product add into cart and add your logic to display price on listing and PDP page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a catalog price rule for that

more info here - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog-create.html

Comment: I give a try, But dont find any option there. There is a option to set any discounted price in percentage or fixed. No option to refer the special price column.

Comment: You need to enable the "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" from catalog attributes for special_price, then you will be able to see Special Price in Conditions in catalog price rule

Comment: I have the attribute enabled for the promo rules and showing in the conditions. But the action tab should let me allow to choose the special price to be taken as a price right, But there I am seeing only 4 options that do not belong to this case